# Алгоритм Дейкстры и Поиск в ширину - жадные алгоритмы

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Являются ли Алгоритм Дейкстры и Поиск в ширину жадными алгоритмами? Если да, то почему?

Comment: А что такое жадные алгоритмы? Применяется ли принцип выбора, свойственный жадным алгоритмам, при реализации Дейкстры и BFS?

Comment: Жадный алгоритм - алгоритм, который каждый шаг ищет самый оптимальный вариант (определение не дословное). Принцип применяется. С алгоритмом Дейкстры все понятно. Там выбирается сосед с наименьшим весом. Но как проявляется оптимальность в каждом шаге в BFS? (Поправьте, если я неправ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жадный выбирает вариант, являющийся оптимальным в данный момент (локальная оптимальность). Для определённых систем такой выбор приводит к глобальному оптимуму.

Да, Дейкстра - жадный алгоритм.

А вот поиск в ширину ничего не выбирает, а просто перебирает все доступные рёбра, и является, таким образом, разновидностью brute-force search ([неинформированный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!